# How do I write an obscene amount of data to file?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I am developing an application that reads lines from enormous text files (~2.5 GB), manipulates each line to a specific format, and then writes each line to a text file. Once the output text file has been closed, the program "Bulk Inserts" (SQL Server) the data into my database. It works, it's just slow.

I am using `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

I'm pretty much stuck with reading one line at a time due to how I have to manipulate the text; however, I think that if I made a collection of lines and wrote out the collection every 1000 lines or so, it would speed things up at least a bit. The problem is (and this could be purely from my ignorance) that I cannot write a `string[]` using `StreamWriter`. After exploring *StackOverflow* and the rest of the internet, I came across `File.WriteAllLines`, which allows me to write `string[]`s to file, but I dont think my computer's memory can handle 2.5 GB of data being stored at one time. Also, the file is created, populated, and closed, so I would have to make a ton of smaller files to break down the 2 GB text files only to insert them into the database. So I would prefer to stay away from that option.

One hack job that I can think of is making a `StringBuilder` and using the `AppendLine` method to add each line to make a gigantic string. Then I could convert that `StringBuilder` to a string and write it to file.

But enough of my conjecturing. The method I have already implemented works, but I am wondering if anyone can suggest a better way to write chunks of data to a file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things will increase the speed of output using `StreamWriter`.

First, make sure that the output file is on a different physical disk than the input file. If the input and output are on the same drive, then very often reads have to wait for writes and writes have to wait for reads. The disk can do only one thing at a time. Obviously not *every* read or write waits, because the `StreamReader` reads into a buffer and parses lines out of it, and the `StreamWriter` writes to a buffer and then pushes that to disk when the buffer is full. With the input and output files on separate drives, your reads and writes overlap.

What do I mean they overlap? The operating system will typically read ahead for you, so it can be buffering your file while you're processing. And when you do a write, the OS typically buffers that and writes it to the disk lazily. So there is some limited amount of asynchronous processing going on.

Second thing is to increase your buffer size. The default buffer size for `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` is 4 kilobytes. So every 4K read or written incurs an operating system call. And, quite likely, a disk operation.

If you increase the buffer size to 64K, then you make 16 times fewer OS calls and 16 times fewer disk operations (not strictly true, but close). Going to a 64K buffer can cut more than 25% off your I/O time, and it's dead simple to do:

```
const int BufferSize = 64 * 1024;
var reader = new StreamReader(filename, Encoding.UTF8, true, BufferSize);
var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, Encoding.UTF8, BufferSize);
```

Those two things will speed your I/O more than anything else you can do. Trying to build buffers in memory using `StringBuilder` is just unnecessary work that does a bad job of duplicating what you can achieve by increasing the buffer size, and done incorrectly can easily make your program *slower*.

I would caution against buffer sizes larger than 64 KB. On some systems, you get marginally better results with buffers up to 256 KB, but on others you get dramatically worse performance--to the tune of 50% slower! I've *never* seen a system perform better with buffers larger than 256 KB than they do with buffers of 64 KB. In my experience, 64 KB is the sweet spot.

One other thing you can do is use three threads: a reader, a processor, and a writer. They communicate with queues. This can reduce your total time from `(input-time + process-time + output-time)` to something very close to `max(input-time, process-time, output-time)`. And with .NET, it's *really* easy to set up. See my blog posts: [Simple multithreading, Part 1](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/16/simple-multithreading-part-1/) and [Simple multithreading, Part 2](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/).

Comment: Good suggestion. I had no idea about setting the buffersize. I also found a good article on this: http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64538/tr-2004-136.pdf

Comment: @khinkle: Thanks for the article link. Good stuff!

Comment: Out of curiosity and inexperience, I would like your opinion of this--that article mentioned that using `FileStreams` can be extremely effective for creating new files because I could use the `SetLength()` method to provide an estimation for how large the file would be. It states, "This lets the file system efficiently pre-allocate the largest possible chunks (the fewest fragments) of physical media to hold all of the file contents and thereby reduce fragmentation." Would this increase efficiency in some significant manner?

Comment: @khinkle: Possibly. The article indicates that it can help reduce fragmentation. You'd have to create the `FileStream`, extend it as the article shows, and then create a `StreamWriter`, passing it that open `FileStream`. Note that there will be some startup cost (creating and extending the file), but if you use the three-thread approach I mentioned, much (perhaps most or even all) of that can happen concurrently, with output lines flowing into the output buffer.

Comment: Brilliant suggestion regarding multithreading. I dont know why I missed that the first time I read through your answer.

Comment: @khinkle: Probably because I added it later.

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer `BlockingCollections` over `ConcurrentQueues` for your parallel IPO implementation?

Comment: @khinkle: I prefer `BlockingCollection` for a number of reasons. Primarily, because it's a much easier interface to use. For example, `GetConsumingEnumerable` is much more convenient than writing a loop that consumes the queue. And the `CompleteAdding` functionality is great, too. `BlockingCollection` gives you a uniform interface to *any* concurrent data structure. I could use it as the interface to a concurrent stack, for example, or a concurrent heap, or any other class that implements `IProducerConsumerCollection`. Its default of `ConcurrentQueue`, though, is really handy.

Answer (score 9):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush(v=vs.100).aspx), `StreamWriter` does not automatically flush after every write by default, so it is buffered.

You could also use some of the lazy methods on the `File` class like so:

```
File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", 
    File.ReadLines("filename.txt").Select(ProcessLine));
```

where `ProcessLine` is declared like so:

```
private string ProcessLine(string input) {
    string result =         // do some calculation on input
    return result;
}
```

Since `ReadLines` is lazy and `WriteAllLines` has a lazy overload, it will stream the file rather than attempting to read the whole thing.

Comment: +1 That's just such an elegant solution. A one-line read-process-output. Gotta love it.

Answer (score 1):

What about building strings to write?

Something like

```
int cnt = 0;
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
while(line = reader.readLine())
{
  cnt++;
  String x = (manipulate line);
  s.append(x+"\n");
  if(cnt%10000 == 0)
  {
     StreamWriter.write(s);
     s=new StringBuilder();
  }
}
```

Edited because comment below is right, should have used stringbuilder.

Comment: Repeated string concatenation is really bad for performance, as a new string must be allocated each time.  That's why StringBuilder exists.

Comment: Good thought. I was thinking along the same lines when I proposed using a `StringBuilder` in my initial question.

Comment: Use [AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb3sbadh(v=vs.100).aspx) rather than `Append(x+'\n')`.

Comment: By the way, `while(line = reader.ReadLine())` doesn't compile. You need to write `while((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)`. Or use `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`, with the `ReadLine` inside the loop.